# Win32 Use a resource font inside the application

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, resources, hwnd

I have an application, and I imported some fonts into the resource.

[image]

Now, I want to use those resourced fonts inside the application, without installing them to the computer that runs it.

**The way I want to use the font resources is** that I want to set a label's font to the resourced font by sending `WM_SETFONT` message to it.

---

Generally, if the font is already installed on the computer I would use the following code:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
//here hwnd is the handle to the window.

const TCHAR* fontName = TEXT("/* THE FONT NAME */");
//this is where I'd enter the font name, but it only works when the font is already installed on the computer.

const long nFontSize = NFONTSIZE(7);
//this is where I set the font size.

LOGFONT logFont = {0};
logFont.lfHeight = -MulDiv(nFontSize, GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
logFont.lfWeight = FW_SEMIBOLD;
_tcscpy_s(logFont.lfFaceName, fontName);

HFONT font = CreateFontIndirect(&logFont); //get the font handle
```

as soon as I get the `HFONT` handle, it's no difficulty to send the `WM_SETFONT` message to the label with:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)font, static_cast<LPARAM>(MAKELONG(TRUE, 0)));
//here hwnd is the handle of the static label.
```

---

But now, I don't want to set the font by this way because this only works when the specified font is already installed on the computer. I have **MY OWN** font file with the `.ttf` format **imported as resource**. I want to set the label's font to **THIS** `.ttf` font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a token `IDF_MYFONT` defined for the resource ID, then you can embed your font in the executable with a line like this in your `.rc` (or `.rc2`) script:

```
IDF_MYFONT BINARY "..\\MyFont.ttf" // Or whatever the path to your font file is.
```

You can load and lock the font resource using code like the following:

```cpp
HANDLE hMyFont = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE; // Here, we will (hopefully) get our font handle
HINSTANCE hInstance = ::GetModuleHandle(nullptr); // Or could even be a DLL's HINSTANCE
HRSRC  hFntRes = FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDF_MYFONT), L"BINARY");
if (hFntRes) { // If we have found the resource ... 
    HGLOBAL hFntMem = LoadResource(hInstance, hFntRes); // Load it
    if (hFntMem != nullptr) {
        void* FntData = LockResource(hFntMem); // Lock it into accessible memory
        DWORD nFonts = 0, len = SizeofResource(hInstance, ares);
        hMyFont = AddFontMemResourceEx(FntData, len, nullptr, &nFonts); // Fake install font!
    }
}
```

Then, when you've finished with the font, you can release it from memory like this:

```cpp
RemoveFontMemResourceEx(hMyFont);
```

I've included *some* checks on the return values for the system calls, but you can add others. And you will need to be able to handle the cases where any of these fail (e.g. providing a default font).

While the font is loaded/locked in memory, you can use it as though it were installed on the system: for example, using its name in a `LOGFONT` structure:

```cpp
LOGFONT MyLogFont = { -8, 0,   0, 0, 400, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET,
                       OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, 
                       VARIABLE_PITCH | FF_SWISS, L"MyFontName" };
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Is there any way to convert this HANDLE  to CFont?

Comment: @DAC84 You can create a `CFont` from the created `LOGFONT` using the `CreateFontIndirect` member of the `CFont` class.

Answer (score 1):

Funny thing, I was just dealing with this problem yesterday night...

To solve it, the values passed into `FindResourceW` must match the resource type:

```
        const auto resourceHandle{ FindResourceW(nullptr, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_FONT1), RT_FONT) };
        const auto resourceLoad{ LoadResource(nullptr, resourceHandle) };
        const auto pResource{ LockResource(resourceLoad) };

        //do something with the resource pointer here...

        FreeResource(resourceLoad);
```

This should give you a pointer to the resource, and you can then extract the font by creating a new file and write to it using `WriteFile.` To get the size of the resource, use `SizeofResource`.

Or you can create the font by passing in the resource pointer into `AddFontMemResourceEx.`